# Rspec works on one computer but not the other

Tags: ruby, rspec

[Desktop with rspec working](http://i.gyazo.com/5cbfb4fc96bd9538a5ad619064654ac9.png)

[Laptop where rspec isn't working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkR4A.png)

I'm pretty sure I installed stuff wrong on my laptop, I can't run tests on my laptop using rspec, it always blasts me with all this text, and doesn't tell me if anything is pending..failed or w.e.

I'm trying to run tests through this ruby kick-start tutorial, and it's not working.  I have no clue what the problem could be. other than a path issue.

When I type in    whereis ruby  it comes out as blank.
While on my desktop it lists a bunch of paths where ruby is at.

Comment: Do you use `git`? it looks like one machine has `spec_helper`, another doesn't. Maybe you added `spec_helper` to project and forgot to push it.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear?  It sounds like what you're saying might be the case, I was trying to do a rspec tutorial then stopped, to study something else which ruined testing with rake and using rspec.

I checked git status and there's nothing to push.

Comment: Your problem is missed `spec_helper` on second machine. Check it

Comment: Oh thanks guys, my bad all I had to do was type rspec --init
I didn't think that because in this separate tutorial it didn't tell me that.